# Primer dilution verification

Tags: primer

I just received a primer (details are displayed in the picture). Since this is my first time doing this, I want to do it correctly. My goal is to make a 10µM primer.
So, If I get it right and based on the paper I received, should I have to add 665μl Sterile distilled water (Inside the primer tube) and then aliquot 90μl Sterile distilled water with 10μl of primer tube mix? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Note that it is not important that the water has been sterilized, it needs to be nuclease free.

Also, for long term storage TE buffer might be a better choice. This will not result in inhibition of your PCR by the EDTA component of the buffer, since the amount of it in the final reaction is neglectable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response as well as for the tip!!!!

Comment: @KGee If this answer helped, make sure to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark